# DialogResult in normal java class and return result

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am working on an android project where I am trying to show a AlertDialog in a separate normal java class and return the result that the user enters. I can display the dialog fine but the problem I am having is it always returns the value before the dialog has had one of the buttons pressed.

Below is the code that calls the function in the standard java class to show the dialog

```
private void showDiagreeError()
{
    Common common = new Common(this);
    boolean dialogResult = common.showYesNoDialog();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result: " + dialogResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And below is the code that shows the actual dialogue

```
public boolean showYesNoDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you do not want to agree to the terms, if you   choose not to, you cannot use Boardies Password Manager")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialogResult = true;
     }
})
.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialogResult = false;
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
return dialogResult;
}
```

dialogResult is a global variable visible throughout the class and being set to false. As soon as the dialog is shown the toast message is shown showing the result is false, but I was expecting the return statement to block until the user has pressed one of the buttons too set the variable to the correct value.

How can I get this to work.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9678418/1210260) for a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours hunting through the inner depths of google pages, I found this [Dialogs / AlertDialogs: How to "block execution" while dialog is up (.NET-style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028697/dialogs-alertdialogs-how-to-block-execution-while-dialog-is-up-net-style).

It does exactly the job I was after and tested to make sure there are no ANR errors, which there isn't